# MySql SELECT with some AND operator

Tags: mysql, search, select, where-clause

i have this table and i want to get result below

```
prod_feat_val Table:

**id**    **prod_id**   **feat_id**      **value**
   1         34             20          touch screen
   2         34             25            stamina
   3         34             27           Android 1.6

   4         12             20             keypad
   5         12             27             android

   6         45             20              touch
   7         45             27             android 4
```

i want to make query that return prod_id(s) by searching in feature value (value). 
example: search for items that have android OS and touch Screen keyboard..it mean return this:

```
 prod_id
    34
    45
```

my query is like than below:

```
SELECT prod_id FROM prod_feat_val 
WHERE 
(feat_id = '27' AND value Like '%android%' ) AND (feat_id = '20' AND value Like '%touch%')
GROUP BY prod_id
```

I think my query is basically wrong, any idea?
if i replace middle AND with OR  then my result may be corrupted (return 34,12,45 ::: Its BAD) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
SELECT prod_id
FROM prod_feat_val 
WHERE 
  (feat_id = '27' AND value Like '%android%' )
  OR (feat_id = '20' AND value Like '%touch%')
GROUP BY
  prod_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT feat_id)=2
```

Since the features you are looking for are on different rows, you need to use OR.

Then you need to group by product_id and count the number of distinct features, and it has to be 2.

Comment: thanks. it work good when we know count of feat_id in search (here:2)....but i think there is a better way to solve this problem!

Comment: if you need to get all products that have all of the features, you need to know how many features you are looking for and you need to do a count. you might skip the distinct clause if (prod_id,feat_id) are unique

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be OR but you've misspelt **touch**.

You have also stated that you want the result to be 34, 45 but your query is searching for 27 and 20.

You could use **SELECT DISTINCT prod_id** rather than GROUP BY but it is not a big deal.

Comment: if i replace OR instead middle AND, result change to prod_id: 34,12,45